# How do i determine the length of a data buffer from a sensor's register map

Tags: c, buffer, sensors, i2c, nrf52

I am busy writing firmware using I2C communication between a nrf52832 SoC and a MAX30102 heart rate sensor. I am busy with a function that writes data to the MAX30102's register as follows:

```c
uint32_t twi_write_buf(uint8_t addr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t *dataOut, uint8_t length)
{
  uint8_t buff[255];
  buff[0] = regAddr;
  memcpy(&buff[1], dataOut, length);

  return nrf_drv_twi_tx(&m_nrf_drv_twi, addr, (const uint8_t *) buff, length + 1, false);
}
```

I then call the function along with the parameters:

```
twi_write_buf(MAX30102, INT_ENABLE_1, 0xCO, ? );
```

I used an example code to help me with the parameters of the function.

- MAX30102 = 0x57(sensor address)
- INT_ENABLE_1 = 0X02 (register address)
- 0XCO(i cannot determine where this parameter comes from when reading the data sheet)
- I am struggling determining the length of this data buffer.

below i have attached a screenshot of the data sheet of the MAX30102. Could anyone please guide me on determining the length of the data buffer and possibly where this 0xC0 data comes from. Thank you

[Register Map of MAX30102](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEAMv.png)

Comment: The 0xC0 value (binary: 11000000) sets the two bits 7 and 6 to one. According to the register map it sets A_FULL_EN to 1 and PPG_RDY_EN to 1 which both belong to the INT_ENABLE_1 register of the device.

Comment: Thanks so much. How do i determine the size of the buffer? as i need to pass it as a parameter to my function twi_write_buf(addr, reg_addr, *dataout, length).......would i just pass 1byte?

Comment: What happens when you try it with one? I'm afraid I can't say anything about it as the function ```nrf_drv_twi_tx``` is unclear to me.

Comment: Sorry i meant to say i need to pass the length parameter to twi_write_buf(). where *dataOut is the pointer to the data buffer and length would be the length of the data buffer. So to my understanding , the hex value 0xC0 is the data buffer and i need to determine the length of the buffer.

Comment: Do you mean to just write 0xc0 to INT_ENABLE_1? This means you're writing array of size 1, so something like `uint8_t buf[1] = { 0xc0 }; twi_write_buf(MAX30102, INT_ENABLE_1, buf, sizeof(buf));` Note that the third argument is not just a number, but pointer to array. `sizeof(buf)` in this case is 1.